# "flutter_cache_manager" package support mtls?

Tags: flutter

I am using "flutter_cache_manager" package to cache some network requests however when implementing mtls I keep getting http 400 Bad Request.

The package documentation/classes descriptions do not have any references to mtls support

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by creating a custom instance with fileService parameter.

```
CacheManager instance = CacheManager(
      Config(
        key,
        stalePeriod: Duration(seconds: 30),
        maxNrOfCacheObjects: 1000,
        fileService: HttpFileService(httpClient: client),
      ),
    );
```